# How to edit 'Index of etc' pages on Nginx and - Make them responsive?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, nginx, directory, directory-listing

I am using Ubuntu Natty 12 and I am using NGINX. (It would insane to consider bloated Apache these days)

What I want to do is edit the default index page templates and add some Meta ViewPorts and styling to them. I know Apache has `IndexHeadInsert`:

```
# META VIEWPORT
IndexHeadInsert "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">"
```

Examples would be then:

http://nginx.org/download/

http://bluu.co.uk/fonts/

https://archive.apache.org/dist/ant/binaries/

Does anyone know where to start on NGINX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nginx has `sub` module for replace part of answer.
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html
It's work well with all answers including autoindex. Just check if your nginx has this module (type `nginx -V`), may be you need `nginx-full` package.

```
location / {
   autoindex on;
   sub_filter_once on;
   sub_filter <head><title> "<head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\"><title>";
}
```

If you need this replace only for one location (/download/, for example), just put it in location block.

```
location = /download/ {
   autoindex on;
   sub_filter_once on;
   sub_filter <head><title> "<head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\"><title>";
}
```

`=` here match /download/ only, but do not match /download/file...

If you have lot of locations and want to keep rules in one place, you can try to redirect 403 error to named location

```
location @subfilter {
   autoindex on;
   sub_filter <head><title> "<head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\"><title>";
}

location = /files/ {
     error_page 403 =200 @subfilter;
}

location = /download/ {
     error_page 403 =200 @subfilter;
}
```

But sub module still wery weak because you can use **only one sub_filter directive** =( It's possible to hack with proxy request to self, but it's bad solution. Better to use 3rd party module https://github.com/yaoweibin/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module

html5, all the same:
`sub_filter "<html>\r\n<head><title>" "<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html>\r\n<head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\"><title>";`

Comment: Is there any way to edit the page structure rather than appending a hack; I want to do this globally.

Comment: No, this is very simple module without any design settings. You can check 3rd party module https://github.com/aperezdc/ngx-fancyindex but I don't know is it supported for modern nginx, and you need to compile nginx for use it.

Comment: If you have few locations... let me edit answer, I'll show you

Comment: Thank you for such a good answer; last question - can I change the HTML to a HTML5 doctype?

Comment: Edited. All the same, just need to add \r\n in right place for match.

Comment: What a fantastic answer that I believe will benefit a lot of people; NGINX should include this by default.